# Boolean Logic disjunction normal form and Simplified DNF

Tags: math, boolean, logic

So I've taken the expression

```
(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)V(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)V(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)
```

all the way down to

```
(P¬∧Q∧R∧¬S)V(R∧S∧¬P)
```

This is right when I input it into `MATLAB` unless 2 cancel each other out. What is the simplest way to make this happen. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this :

```
(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)V(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)V(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)
```

when simplified becomes this :

```
(¬P∧¬Q∧R∧S)
```

but not this :

```
(P¬∧Q∧R∧¬S)V(R∧S∧¬P)
```

Comment: my simplification works in MATLAB, unless two bits are wrong and cause the outcome to become positive.

Comment: that itself shows that you've made some mistake in your simplification  @JamesDonnelly